# Google Maps analogue of QuickOSM / Overpass?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins, google-maps-api, overpass-api

Is there a Google Maps analogue of QGIS's [QuickOSM](https://docs.3liz.org/QuickOSM/) plugin? I would like to download data from Google Maps, similarly to how [Overpass](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) gets data from [OSM](https://www.openstreetmap.org/), using a Google Maps API key.

Comment: no, google purchase the map data under license (bottom right corner), OSM is crowdsourced and under open data common licenses https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright

Comment: @Mapperz , but I have a Google Maps API key.

Comment: API key only allows for using (not downloading) Google Maps Services. Please read the Google Map Terms. Seek professional legal advice. We are not lawyers.

Comment: @Mapperz There's already a plugin that allows using Google Maps's API key: [GeoCoding](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GeoCoding/).